# iOS navigationItem title with custom font loses vertical centering

Tags: ios, text, attributes, navigationitem

Is there any text attribute like line-height or any other feature that would help with vertical centering of a `UINavigationItem` title? After setting custom font it is higher than standard one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, there is a method on UINavigationBar named

```
- (void)setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:(CGFloat)adjustment forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

Comment: You are my own God, mister :D ha! i do tego z Warszawy! pozdrawiam

Comment: Widzę, że polska społeczność w SO rośnie ;)